# invoke tinymce with javascript - in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

While in the wordpress admin, I would like to invoke a tinymce text editor using javascript (on a user click event... i.e. after page load).

I am able to call the editor but it doesnt look like the wp editor and the custom buttons I created for the editor are not showing up either.

How can I call the tinymce editor via javascript using all the same settings as the wordpress post/page editor?

```
 tinyMCE.init({
   mode:"exact",
   width:"100%",
   theme:"advanced",
   skin:"wp_theme",
   editor_selector : "mceAdvanced"+tick
 });
```

Comment: Why don't you use the wp_editor in a hidden div, which appears on click ?

Comment: i think that may be easier. thanks!